# Lebesgue differentiation theorem and mollifiers

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $F(x,u)$ be Caratheodory function. i.e.

- $F(x,\cdot)$ is continous for a.e. with respect to $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and
- $F(\cdot,u)$ measurable for $u.$

In addition, assume that $F(x,\cdot)$ is Lipschitz continuous and $F(x,0)=0.$

Now, suppose $u \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$: how to prove the following statement?
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} F(x,u(y))\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y) \phi(x)dx dy= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}F(x,u(x))\phi(x)dx
\end{eqnarray}
P.S.: I do understand that we have to apply Lebesgue differentiation theorem but I am looking for a proper justification.
For example what guarantees the measurability of the set
$$
\left\{x\in\Bbb R: \lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} F(x,u(y))\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y) dy=0\right\}\;?
$$

Comment: The integral on the right might not exist (i.e. $F=u^2$ and $u\not\in L^2(0,1)$).

Comment: @daw I have added additional assumptions to ensure the integrability.